# Why do I get the exception "Found ambiguous parameter type"? Spring Batch Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am learning Spring Batch Integration from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages) and I know how to launch a job when a message is received. Now, I wanted to get both the name and path of the message (which is a file). Below are my working codes. However, if I uncomment the `setFileParameterName` method, then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName(java.lang.String), public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(org.springframework.batch.core.Job)]
```

Why does this exception occur? The message makes no sense to me. I pass in a String and it is somehow confused between the two methods, but one of them takes in a String and the other a Job? Any help with this is appreciated.

**FileMessageToJobRequest.java**

```
public class FileMessageToJobRequest {

private String filePathParameterName;
private Job job;
private String fileParameterName;

public void setFilePathParameterName(String filePathParameterName) {
    this.filePathParameterName = filePathParameterName;
}

public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}

//  public void setFileParameterName(String fileParameterName) {
//      this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
//  }

@Transformer
public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) throws IOException {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
//      jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName, message.getPayload().getName());
    jobParametersBuilder.addString(filePathParameterName, message.getPayload().getCanonicalPath());
    jobParametersBuilder.addDate("dummy", new Date()); // need to add at least one unique identifier so that it will run more than once
    return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
}

}
```

**BatchIntegrationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchIntegrationConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

@Bean
public MessageChannel files() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
    FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
//      fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name")
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setFilePathParameterName("input.file.path");
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(runBatchScriptJob());
    return fileMessageToJobRequest;
}

@Bean
public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
    JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);

    return jobLaunchingGateway;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("./src/main/resources")).
            filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("simplebatchfile.bat")),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}

@Bean
public Job runBatchScriptJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("runBatchScriptJob")
            .listener(new JobCompletionNotificationListener())
            .start(runBatchScriptStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step runBatchScriptStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("runBatchScriptStep")
            .tasklet(runBatchScriptTasklet(null))
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet runBatchScriptTasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.path']}") String filePath) {
    RunBatchScriptTasklet tasklet = new RunBatchScriptTasklet();
    tasklet.setFilePath(filePath);
    return tasklet;
}

}
```

**StackTrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationFlow' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'integrationFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName(java.lang.String), public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(org.springframework.batch.core.Job)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchProcessingApplication.main(BatchProcessingApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'integrationFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName(java.lang.String), public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(org.springframework.batch.core.Job)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName(java.lang.String), public void com.example.batchprocessing.FileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(org.springframework.batch.core.Job)]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:176) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.validateFallbackMethods(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:755) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:740) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:294) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:225) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:62) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:39) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.java:960) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:510) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.java:939) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:503) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition.java:926) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:498) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchIntegrationConfiguration.integrationFlow(BatchIntegrationConfiguration.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$238a9f8a.CGLIB$integrationFlow$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$238a9f8a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b8a5aaf.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$238a9f8a.integrationFlow(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one `handle(fileMessageToJobRequest())` has to be changed to the  `transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())` since your `FileMessageToJobRequest` is really a `@Transformer`. The `handle()` doesn't understand that annotation and tries to figure out any candidate method to execute at runtime.

The message `Found ambiguous parameter type` means that there are several methods with different parameters which can be as message handling candidates. In this case we need to be more specific. Like your `@Transformer` is a good marker, but it is used from the wrong place - the `handle()` is for a `@ServiceActivator`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing from `handle()` to `transform()` worked. One point I would like to bring up is that in the link I put in my post (which is the official Spring docs), `handle()` is used instead of `transform()` so wouldn't that be a bit misleading?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please, raise an issue for Spring Batch project. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: No, no, thank you for your help. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues cc and press `New`